# Negative feedback - where can I find more information?

Tags: facebook-like, feedback

I received an email of my app receiving "High amount of negative feedback", and this:
"Specifically, users are responding negatively to your app Liking content."

It's possible to like using my app, but I'm carefully following the liking policies (also listed in the email): not liking on behalf of users, it's always clear what is being liked, no real-world incentives tied in, etc.

Where can I find more info on what this negative feedback actually is?

The insights pages show a low number of likes per post, does this count as negative feedback?